# Automating a script on a cell value change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, scripting

I am a complete novice to Google Script for Sheets.

I have a script that works to geocode an address. It works when I select the three columns "Address", "Lat", "Lng" and press the Geocode tab. However, when I use it, I have to press that tab, and then select "run script on selected cells" before it will work.

So, what I am after:
If an address is entered using another app, into the cell J2 (for example), I would want Google Sheets to **automatically** select J2, K2, and L2, then run the geocode script on those cells.

I hope that makes sense?

Sorry, but my script knowledge is minimal, but I can follow clear instructions if anyone is able to help.

Here is the code:

```
  return PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('GEOCODING_REGION') || 'us';
}

/*
function setGeocodingRegion(region) {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('GEOCODING_REGION', region);
  updateMenu();
}
function promptForGeocodingRegion() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Set the Geocoding Country Code (currently: ' + getGeocodingRegion() + ')',
    'Enter the 2-letter country code (ccTLD) that you would like ' +
    'the Google geocoder to search first for results. ' +
    'For example: Use \'uk\' for the United Kingdom, \'us\' for the United States, etc. ' +
    'For more country codes, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );
  // Process the user's response.
  if (result.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    setGeocodingRegion(result.getResponseText());
  }
}
*/

function addressToPosition() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cells = sheet.getActiveRange();

  // Must have selected 3 columns (Address, Lat, Lng).
  // Must have selected at least 1 row.

  if (cells.getNumColumns() != 3) {
    Logger.log("Must select at least 3 columns: Address, Lat, Lng columns.");
    return;
  }

  var addressColumn = 1;
  var addressRow;

  var latColumn = addressColumn + 1;
  var lngColumn = addressColumn + 2;

  var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().setRegion(getGeocodingRegion());
  var location;

  for (addressRow = 1; addressRow <= cells.getNumRows(); ++addressRow) {
    var address = cells.getCell(addressRow, addressColumn).getValue();

    // Geocode the address and plug the lat, lng pair into the 
    // 2nd and 3rd elements of the current range row.
    location = geocoder.geocode(address);

    // Only change cells if geocoder seems to have gotten a 
    // valid response.
    if (location.status == 'OK') {
      lat = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
      lng = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];

      cells.getCell(addressRow, latColumn).setValue(lat);
      cells.getCell(addressRow, lngColumn).setValue(lng);
    }
  }
};

function positionToAddress() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cells = sheet.getActiveRange();

  // Must have selected 3 columns (Address, Lat, Lng).
  // Must have selected at least 1 row.

  if (cells.getNumColumns() != 3) {
    Logger.log("Must select at least 3 columns: Address, Lat, Lng columns.");
    return;
  }

  var addressColumn = 1;
  var addressRow;

  var latColumn = addressColumn + 1;
  var lngColumn = addressColumn + 2;

  var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().setRegion(getGeocodingRegion());
  var location;

  for (addressRow = 1; addressRow <= cells.getNumRows(); ++addressRow) {
    var lat = cells.getCell(addressRow, latColumn).getValue();
    var lng = cells.getCell(addressRow, lngColumn).getValue();

    // Geocode the lat, lng pair to an address.
    location = geocoder.reverseGeocode(lat, lng);

    // Only change cells if geocoder seems to have gotten a 
    // valid response.
    Logger.log(location.status);
    if (location.status == 'OK') {
      var address = location["results"][0]["formatted_address"];

      cells.getCell(addressRow, addressColumn).setValue(address);
    }
  }  
};

function generateMenu() {
  // var setGeocodingRegionMenuItem = 'Set Geocoding Region (Currently: ' + getGeocodingRegion() + ')';

  // {
  //   name: setGeocodingRegionMenuItem,
  //   functionName: "promptForGeocodingRegion"
  // },

  var entries = [{
    name: "Geocode Selected Cells (Address to   Lat, Long)",
    functionName: "addressToPosition"
  },
  {
    name: "Geocode Selected Cells (Address from Lat, Long)",
    functionName: "positionToAddress"
  }];

  return entries;
}

function updateMenu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().updateMenu('Geocode', generateMenu())
}

/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the readRows() function specified above.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 *
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Geocode', generateMenu());
  // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Region',  generateRegionMenu());
  // SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  //   .createMenu();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest onEdit() trigger, but as you'll not be updating the Spreasheet manually but programmatically, onEdit() trigger won't work for you because triggers are only triggered if the action is done manually [1]. I suggest you use a time-driven trigger, to update the sheet every given time [1], for example:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(6)
      .create();

  // Trigger every Monday at 09:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}
```

You could obtain the entire data with getDataRange() function [2] and use the values to update all the rows. Other option would be to save the number of rows in an attribute with the Properties Service [3] and use it to compare how many new rows are they and update only those new rows.

**UPDATE**

After reviewing you comments I put together the following code:

```
function getGeocodingRegion() {
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('GEOCODING_REGION') || 'us';
}

function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("addressToPosition")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(15)
  .create();
}

function addressToPosition() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]").getSheets()[0];
  var cells = sheet.getRange("M2:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().setRegion(getGeocodingRegion());
  var location;
  var locationsArray = [];

  for (var addressRow = 0; addressRow<cells.length; addressRow++) {
    var address = cells[addressRow][0];
    locationsArray[addressRow] = [];
    var err;
    // Geocode the address and plug the lat, lng pair into the 
    // 2nd and 3rd elements of the current range row.
    try{
      location = geocoder.geocode(address);
    }
    catch(error) {
      err = error;
      Logger.log(err);
    }

    // Only change cells if geocoder seems to have gotten a 
    // valid response.
    if (location.status == 'OK') {
      var lat = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
      var lng = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];

      locationsArray[addressRow][0] = lat;
      locationsArray[addressRow][1] = lng;
    }
    else {
      locationsArray[addressRow][0] = err;
      locationsArray[addressRow][1] = err;
    }
  }

  //Set all latitudes and longitudes 
  sheet.getRange("N2:O" + sheet.getLastRow()).setValues(locationsArray);  
}
```

You need to replace your Spreadsheet ID and run the createTimeDrivenTrigger function once, which will create the trigger to run addressToPosition function every 15 min. This will find the last row on the first Sheet, get the addresses from column M and put the latitudes and longitudes in columns N and O respectively.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties

Comment: Thank you. I put that in the script ecditor, but I get an error which says "The passed in argument must be greater than zero. (line 6, file "Code")" which is the create() line... I am a complete novice, so I don't know how to fix that. :/

Comment: May be a problem with the function you're linking, It should be linked to a function that doesn't require any argument. You have to replace 'myFunction' for the name of your function. Review the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable || https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to link it to all the functions in turn. no joy. Basically, the code I put in the original post is what I am using. I want to get rid of the Menu creating bit, and I only want the AddressToLocation part. I want the script to run automatically at intervals, and when it does, select a range (M2:O999) and then run the addressToLocation function, which puts Lat and Long in the relevant columns. If it's any easier, I have named the range M2:O999 as LatLongCalc...  Not having much luck, and sadly, reading the help docs just confuses me more. :(

Comment: Which is the time interval you want it to run?

Comment: To begin with, maybe 15 minutes? I may change that later, as once the data is in the spreadsheet, there are not going to be many more added, except maybe one a day... but initially, I will need to enter a lot of data, which will need the geocoding...

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but the script has stopped working. it was woreking brilliantly, and now it just stopped. Any ideas what might cause that?

Comment: How isn't working? Provide the error message.. and please consider accepting the answer as correct.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message. :( How do I mark an answer as correct? It was working a couple of days ago. I looked today and nothing. Would adding a couple of columns AFTER the ones we are working with change anything?

Comment: 1) I added a logger in the code, you can run it manually and see if there's an error on the log. 2) In your script, go to Current project's triggers and check if the trigger is still there (It should if you didn't delete it).

Comment: On one of my spreadsheets, I get this error: [19-11-14 01:04:33:896 PST] Exception: Invalid argument: location. On the other one, I get nothing, just seems to weait while running the addressToPosition function. To do these, I had to run the functions separately, manually, as well.

Comment: Do you have the `GEOCODING_REGION` property set? Are you using US addresses or addresses within the specified `GEOCODING_REGION`? The code also depends on the last row with data, if the last row with data is too low (high row number) it might take too long to run the code.

Comment: I get this now: TypeError: Cannot read property "status" from undefined. (line 36, file "Code") I am using UK addresses... but the code worked before, so the region must have been ok, unless somethinhg has changed there?

Comment: You're getting the error because  the logic related to the Maps logic, either this line: ` var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().setRegion(getGeocodingRegion());` or this one ` location = geocoder.geocode(address);` are causing problems. Check the Maps Service on how can you fix it for your purpose: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder#setRegion(String).

Comment: I looked there, and can't make out what I am supposed to do. Thanks for your help, anyway. I'll have to keep trying things and seeing if I can make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Specifically, the `onEdit()` function seems to be what you need.

Based on what I can gather from the docs, that trigger doesn't differentiate among cells: if any cell in the sheet is edited, it gets called. But you could check the specific cells or range that you're interested in and take actions accordingly.

It would also be a good idea to post some pseudocode or code snippets explaining what you have done, because it'll be easier to show you how to integrate a solution into your existing code.

Comment: Ok. Am I ok to just post code then? I got it from another site, and was given there freely to take, just wasn't sure about posting it.

Comment: I suppose what I am mostly interested in, is that this does all the things I need AUTOMATICALLY. Someone else will be suing the app that fills in these cells, and they won;t have access to the actual sheet...

Comment: SO i will need the script to select a specific cell that had an address added(Other cells will have changed as well) and then select the two cells immediately to the right of it, and then run the script on those three cells. I'll pst the script in another comment on the original post